# How to insert a NULL into a timestamp with timezone column into Postgres using C# client and generic parameter API

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have a column in a table whose type is set to Timestamp with time zone. I am calling a function (whose argument is also of type Timestamp with time zone) to insert rows into the table. I am using the generic parameter API and I need to be able to set the value to NULL.
I cannot use

```
command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<DateTime>("p_responded", null));
```

I get a compilation error that there is no constructor. So I tried using a nullable DT:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<DateTime?>("p_responded", null));
```

I get the following exception

> System.InvalidCastException: Cannot write DateTime with Kind=UTC to PostgreSQL type 'timestamp without time zone', consider using 'timestamp with time zone'. Note that it's not possi
> ble to mix DateTimes with different Kinds in an array/range. See the Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior AppContext switch to enable legacy behavior.

Comment: Have you tried `command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<DateTime>("p_responded", (DateTime)null));`?

Comment: @PalleDue you cannot have a null ```DateTime``` since they are structs.

Comment: @YungDeiza: Of course, thanks for pointing out my bad.

Comment: Is there a third Parameter to specify DateTime Kind?

Comment: Can you not just do `command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<DateTime?>{ParameterName = "p_responded"});`

Comment: @Charlieface Same exception. Guess not

Comment: @Charlieface I tried using a regular DateTime and not setting the value. That results in a -infinity in the DB. Whatever that means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporting null with the generic parameter API is tracked in https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/3679.

In the meantime, use the non-generic parameter API and pass DBNull.Value.

Comment: Thanks Shay. I was about to tweet you the same question. It is only under certain conditions that we want to set null. Very seldom. We use the generic parameter API to avoid the boxing penalty. Can we mix and match the way the parameters are added?

Comment: Also discovered that I can use command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter<DateTimeOffset?>("p_responded", null)); without setting legacy flags 
Is that OK?

Comment: Sorry last one. I see that there is support for Noda Time. Does that support writing a NULL to the DB using the generic parameter API?

Comment: NodaTime isn't different on this - the problem is in general for writing null for *value* types via the generic parameter API. Until there's a better solution, you can simply check if the value is null, and if so, use the non-generic parameter API; it should be easy to wrap this in an extension method and use everywhere.